# WP7 delete item from listBox via message box

Tags: windows-phone-7, listboxitems

need some help, when i click the tap_event I get a message box delete or cancel which works and the price is taken off the total but it does'nt update the shopping cart after, it crashes on "ListBoxCart.Items.Remove(curr), thanks in advance!

```
    private void listBoxCart_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure!", "Delete", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel)
            == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {

            foreach (Dvd curr in thisapp.ShoppingCart)
            {
                if (curr.Equals(listBoxCart.SelectedItem))
                {
                    listBoxCart.Items.Remove(curr);
                    listBoxCart.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    total -= Convert.ToDecimal(curr.price);

                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ShoppingCart.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                }


            }
            txtBoxTotal.Text = total.ToString();
            listBoxCart.ItemsSource = thisapp.ShoppingCart;
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ShoppingCart.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }


    }
```

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Comment: sorry and operation not supported on read-only collection.

Comment: You can't remove items from a listbox.  You need to remove items from the supplied item collection.

Comment: @Fabrice Thank you for your quick response, I was taking the wrong approach altogether, I can only add to/delete from a collection not a listBox, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrote an artile (sorry in french but you can read the XAML) : http://www.peug.net/2012/05/17/contextmenu-dans-listbox-datatemplate/

and in the code-behind : an example :

```
    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
        var fe = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(menuItem) as FrameworkElement;
        Dvd _fig = fe.DataContext as Dvd;
        thisapp.ShoppingCart.Remove(_fig);

        reloading();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `ItemsSource` property for the ListBox, it generates a `read-only` collection and displays them. What you're trying to do is access this read-only collection and modify it but because it's read-only, you can't do that.

Instead you can either have your collection implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and raise a collection changed event when the user has deleted the item or use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms668604.aspx) instead to store your items. `ObservableCollection` implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface for you so you can [remove items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms132413.aspx) from the `ObservableCollection` and the changes will reflect in the Listbox automatically.

ObservableCollection also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so any property updates will also be updated in the ListBox.